# How to avoid system hang because of infinite loop?

Tags: java, loops, error-handling, while-loop, sublimetext3

I use Java with Sublime and print the output in a separate file instead of in the terminal. When I run into infinite loops, too much is printed into the file and the system sort of hangs, and sublime starts throwing notifications to reload the file on disk. When I reload, the code editing is slow until I reopen Sublime.

How do I avoid these crashes from infinite loops in cases where I miss them completely?

This is my boiler plate btw.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class testing {
    public static class Task {
        public void solve(Scanner sc, PrintWriter pw) throws IOException {
            
    }
}
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new FileReader(System.getenv("INPUT")));
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(System.getenv("OUTPUT"))));
    // Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    // PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(System.out));
    Task t = new Task();
    int T = sc.nextInt();
    while (T-- > 0)
        t.solve(sc, pw);
    pw.close();
}

}

class Scanner {
    private StringTokenizer st;
    private BufferedReader br;
    public Scanner(InputStream s) {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s));
    }
    public Scanner(FileReader s) throws FileNotFoundException {
        br = new BufferedReader(s);
    }
    public String next() throws IOException {
        while (st == null || !st.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                return null;
            }
            st = new StringTokenizer(line);
        }
        return st.nextToken();
    }

public int nextInt() throws IOException {
    String token = next();
    if (token == null) {
        // Handle the case where there's no more input
        // You can throw an exception, return a default value, or handle it as needed.
        return 0;
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(token);
}
public long nextLong() throws IOException {
    return Long.parseLong(next());
}
public String nextLine() throws IOException {
    return br.readLine();
}
public double nextDouble() throws IOException {
    return Double.parseDouble(next());
}
public int[] readIntArray(int n) throws IOException {
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = nextInt();
    return arr;
}
public long[] readLongArray(int n) throws IOException {
    long[] arr = new long[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = nextLong();
    return arr;
}

public boolean ready() throws IOException {
    return br.ready();
}
public void trace(int[] arr) {
    System.err.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
public void trace(Integer[] arr) {
    System.err.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
public void trace(long[] arr) {
    System.err.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
public void trace(Long[] arr) {
    System.err.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
public void trace(char[] arr) {
    System.err.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
public void trace(Character[] arr) {
    System.err.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
public void trace(Collection<?> collection) {
    System.err.println(collection);
}
public void trace(Map<?, ?> map) {
    System.err.println(map);
}
public void trace(int a, int... b) {
    System.err.print(a + " ");
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length - 1; i++) {
        System.err.print(b[i] + " ");
    }
    System.err.println(b[b.length - 1]);
}
public void trace(double a, double... b) {
    System.err.print(a + " ");
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length - 1; i++) {
        System.err.print(b[i] + " ");
    }
    System.err.println(b[b.length - 1]);
}
public void trace(long a, long... b) {
    System.err.print(a + " ");
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length - 1; i++) {
        System.err.print(b[i] + " ");
    }
    System.err.println(b[b.length - 1]);
}
public void trace(char a, char... b) {
    System.err.print(a + " ");
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length - 1; i++) {
        System.err.print(b[i] + " ");
    }
    System.err.println(b[b.length - 1]);
}
}
```

Comment: Theoretically, this can't be done, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem . In practice, just put a counter into your application and abort if the counter exceeds your expected outcome. And throw an Exception so you can get a hint on what is going wrong.

Comment: As far as the Sublime aspect goes, it retains the state of windows across restarts, which includes not only the list of open files but also unsaved changes. If your output file is open and massively large, then Sublime will attempt to re-open it (or worse, if you modify the content, store the entire thing as unsaved changes); so maybe delete the output file from disk before restarting or such. Hard to say based on your description.